# Netty server not shutdown correctly when running locally

Tags: netty

I have a problem when running Netty client and server in same jvm and try to stop server. Here is my code to exemplify this:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new DefaultLocalServerChannelFactory());
    serverBootstrap.getPipeline().addLast("my-server-handler", new ServerHandler());
    LocalAddress local = new LocalAddress("1");
    serverChannel = serverBootstrap.bind(local);

    clientBootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(new DefaultLocalClientChannelFactory());

    clientBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
            pipeline.addLast("my-client-handler", new ClientHandler());
            return pipeline;
        }
    });

    ChannelFuture future = clientBootstrap.connect(local);
    if (future.isSuccess())
        System.out.println("Client connected");
    clientChannel = future.getChannel();
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    closeServer();
    clientChannel.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
    clientBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
}

@Test
public void shoulClose() {        
    sendData();
    closeServer();
    sendData();       
}

private void closeServer() {
    serverChannel.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
    serverBootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
}

private void sendData() {
    clientChannel.write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

I have tested this with Netty 3.4.0.Final and 3.4.4.Final and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Why can the client still send data to server after the server has been taken down?

Answer (score 0):

The client can send data but the ChannelFuture of clientChannel.write(..) should fail.

You can check it with:

```
boolean success = clientChannel.write(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 }).awaitUninteruptable().isSucess();
```

Or use a ChannelFutureListener to get notifed in a async fashion.